# JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 16635

Tags: joomla-3.x

When I log into my joomla site from the front end I get this warning.

> JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 16635

But that user doesn't exist.

From searching it might be easiest to just create a user with that ID but I'd like to understand more about why this is happening please?

Mat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sometimes happens when a specific user has been deleted that was the author of an article or any other content. When trying to load that content, it also tries to get the username based on the ID, which cannot be found in the `#__users` table.

If you have an article being displayed on the homepage, try changing the author to someone else.

If this doesn't work:

1. Create a new user via the Joomla User Manager (admin backend).
2. Open your database manager such as PhpMyAdmin
3. Go to the `#__users` table and search for the ID of the user you just created
4. Change the `ID` for this user to `16635`
5. Go to the `#__user_usergroup_map` table
6. Search for the `user_id` that matches the ID of the user you created before
7. Change this also to `16635`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

To change this for a specific article in the backend, in the article edit screen, go to the **Publishing Tab** and find the author field - which is called **Created By**.

[image: Article - Publishing Settings]

Click the blue button, which will open a modal window with the available Site Users to select a new user for the author of the article.

[image: Select new author]

Select the user and save the article.

Comment: This is a much quicker and easier solution than the selected answer. Thanks!