# Why is this user being loaded? 16635

Tags: joomla-3.x

Following up to this question: [JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 16635](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13633/juser-load-unable-to-load-user-with-id-16635)

I've added the userid back but I am still perturbed by the user loading at all. How can I track this down? What are some suggestions?

Not a duplicate because now I want to understand methods to track down why the user is being loaded.

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: You have the answer in your first question why it happens.

Comment: Which part of the first question answered it?

Comment: `When trying to load that content, it also tries to get the username based on the ID, which cannot be found in the #__users table.` That is one of examples. Any extension can query that user, but there is no way to track it.